# PHP install fails on file does not exist

Tags: php, apache, installation

on cmd: `C:\Apache24\bin>httpd -t`
Received message:

> httpd: Syntax error on line 540 of C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load C:/php/php8apache2_4.dll into server: The specified module could not be found.>

And, in fact, C:\php\php8apache2_4.dll does not exist in my C:\php folder.

Do I specify a different php8 ... .dll or must I find and install the php8apache2_4.dll? And if the latter, where do I look?

Background:
Based on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oJnCEqeAsUk&t=4s entitled "Install & Set Up Apache Web Server on Windows 10", I installed Apache/2.4.55(Win64) server after download and extract from Apache Lounge into the C:\Apache folder I created.

Based on https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-install-php-on-windows/#installingphp I created a C:\php folder into which I extracted a downloaded PHP from the x64 Thread Safe ZIP package from https://windows.php.net/download/ . I renamed a copy of C:\php\php.ini-development to C:\php\php.ini. Then enabled `extension=curl, extension=gd, extension=mbstring and extension=pdo_mysql`. I then added C:\php to the PATH system environment variables.

I then opened C:\Apache24\conf\httpd.conf and added
`# PHP8 module`
`PHPIniDir "C:/php"`
`LoadModule php_module "C:/php/php8apache2_4.dll"`
`AddType application/x-httpd-php .php`
and changed dir_module to read:
`<IfModule dir_module>`
    `DirectoryIndex index.php index.html`
`</IfModule>`

Then, from the command line I attempted
`cd C:\Apache24\bin`
`httpd -t`

Upon which I received the "could not be found module" message.

I am running MS Windows 10 Home Version 19044 on a Dell Inspiron 15-3567 Dell laptop x-64 based PC

Comment: I downloaded php-8.1.15-Win32-vs16-x64.zip a few days ago and it did contain a file called `php8apache2_4.dll`. Can you verify the original ZIP or download it again? Perhaps you didn't extract it, or you removed it by mistake, or your antivirus did...

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález My download was php-8.2.3-nts-Win32-vs16-x64.zip. I'll try to uninstall and download and install  php-8.1.15-Win32-vs16-x64.zip . Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález That did it -- thanks. Will try to contact and alert the author that his article is outdated.

Comment: "downloaded PHP from the x64 Thread Safe ZIP package" - Apparently you didn't. "nts" stands for non-thread-safe.